# Splitting of poisson process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

$\{N(t), t\geq 0\}$ is a Poisson process. If I classify all the odd events in the process as one type and even events into other type, I get two counting processes.

$N_i(t)$ be the number of type $i$ events that occur during $(0,t].$ $(i=1,2)$.

Am I correct in saying that I have used Bernoulli splitting of the given process with probabilities $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$. And the new $N_i(t)$ are also Poisson processes and that they are independent of each other?

Comment: No, in Bernoulli splitting each event is tagged randomly independently of the others while here, the tag of one event determines the tag of the next event. Note that $N_1(t)-N_2(t)\in\{0,1\}$ almost surely, for every $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{T_n:n=1,2,\ldots\}$ be the arrival times of $\{N(t)\}$. If we define \begin{align}
N_1(t) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf 1_{(0,t]}(T_{2n-1})\\
N_2(t) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathsf 1_{(0,t]}(T_{2n}),
\end{align}
then $\{T_{2(n+1)-1}-T_{2n-1}\}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of $\mathrm{Erlang}(2,\lambda)$ random variables, as is $\{T_{2(n+1)}-T_{2n}\}$. So $\{N_1(t)\}$ and $\{N_2(t)\}$ are renewal processes each with interrenewal density $$(\lambda t)\lambda e^{-\lambda t}\mathsf 1_{(0,\infty)}(t) $$ (where $\lambda>0$ is the intensity of $\{N(t)\}$) but are not independent, as $$\mathbb P(N_1(t)-N_2(t)\in\{0,1\})=1$$ for all $t\geqslant 0$.

Let $Z(t)=N_1(t)-N_2(t)$, then $\{Z(t):t\in\mathbb R_+\}$ is an alternating renewal process with uptime and downtime distributions both $\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$. That is pretty much all that can be said of this deterministically split Poisson process, I believe.

Comment: Sorry, I have not been introduced to renewal process. Can you explain in other ways to show that $N_i$ are not Poisson process

Comment: A Poisson process is a renewal process in which the interrenewal times are exponentially distributed. So yes, you have been introduced to renewal processes :)