# Odd event in counting process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let's say $\{X_1,X_2,X_3,...\}$ is a set of positive IID random variable has distribution on a general distribution F

The summation of these random variable is a renewal sequence

$$S_n=X_1+X_2+X_3+...+X_n$$

Let N(t) define as a counting process that $ N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbf{1}_{(0,t]}(S_n)$.

We would like to find the probability that $P[N(t) \text{ is odd}]$

My reasoning for this problem is define a new $N'(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{(0,t]}(S_{2n-1})$ but I have no idea how to derive the probability out of $N'(t)$ since the distribution of $X$ is general. My guess is that $P(N'(t))$ will be some kind of renewal type equation.

This is a question that I think is a general version for the [splitting event of Poisson process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950256/splitting-of-poisson-process) discussed before.

**Update 1**

I tried to borrow the idea from [Poisson process splitting problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950256/splitting-of-poisson-process). The interarrival time for the new counting process $N'(t)$ is $X_i+X_{i+1}$ which is the convolution of the distribution $F(t)*F(t)=F^{2*}$. If we know about the new interarrival distribution, can we derive the probability out of it?

**Update 2**

I think I come up a solution but I would appriciate if others could check my answer.

For a renewal process $$N(t) \ge  n \Leftrightarrow S_n \leq t$$ *(I do confuse about this relation but it appears in many stochastic process textbooks)*

Therefore

$$
\begin{align}
P[N(t) = n] &= P[N(t)\ge n]-P[N(t) \ge n+1] \\
&=P[S_n \le t]-P[S_{n+1} \le t]
\end{align}
$$

Thus

$$
\begin{align}
P(N(t) \text{ is odd}) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\{P(S_{2n-1}\le t) - P(S_{2n}\le t)\} \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(F^{(2n-1)*}-F^{(2n)*})
\end{align}
$$

Here, $F^{n*}$ is n-fold convolution for the distribution F (from sum of random r.v)

Comment: So the $X_i$ are your wait times? And you want the probability that at time $t$, an odd number of renewals has occurred?

Comment: Wouldn't $P(N'(t))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}P_{(0,t]}(S_n)$? I guess that goes without saying, though.  You're probably looking for something more specific?

Comment: $X_i$ can be seen as waiting time between counting. Yes, I would like to know the probability that the probability that the counting is odd at given time t.

Comment: Is the formula I gave sufficient, or do you need more? Sorry I just realized that I put $P(N'(t)$ when I meant $P[N(t) \text{ is odd}]
$, so it should be $P[N(t) \text{ is odd}]
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}P_{(0,t]}(S_n)$

Comment: @GabrielBurns Could you explain how to get the summation expression in the comment? I think I need to derive the $P_{(0,t]}(S_n)$ to a complete form also.

Comment: $P_{(0,t]}\left(S_n\right)$ is the probability that the count reaches $n$ within the interval $(0,t]$.  Thus $P(N(t)=n)=P_{(0,t]}\left(S_n\right)-P_{(0,t]}\left(S_{n+1}\right)$. Since we are interested in  $P[N(t) \text{ is odd}]$, we take the sum for all odd $n$ which gives the alternating sum in my comment.

Comment: @GabrielBurns I come up a solution with your hint in previous comment. Would you like to check? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $N(t)\ge n \leftrightarrow S_n\le t$?  I know that's not the part you wanted checked, but still...  Also the LHS of the second part should be $P[N(t)= n]$, and the RHS of the third part should be summed over all $n$.

Comment: @GabrielBurns I am still unclear about the alternative sum that results to sum of odd components. If we plugin $n$ then $P[N(t) \text{ is odd}] =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}P_{(0,t]}(S_n) = 1*P_{(0,t]}(S_1)-1*P_{(0,t]}(S_2)+1*P_{(0,t]}(S_3)+....$ It did summing up the odd number but also minus the probability of even number. In our case, I guess we would like the Pr for even number to be 0.

Comment: Remember that $P_{(0,t]}(S_n)$ Is the probability that $N(t)\ge n$. In other words, it is the probability that at time $t$ we have counted ***at least*** $n$ times.  What we want is to find the probability (at time $t$) that we have counted ***exactly*** $n$ times, and then take the sum of this for all odd $n$.  The probability of counting exactly $n$ times is $$P[N(t)=n]=P[N(t)\ge n] - P[N(t)\gt n]$$$$=P[N(t) \ge n] - P[N(t)\ge n+1]$$$$=P_{(0,t]}(S_n)-P_{(0,t]}(S_{n+1})$$   Taking the sum of this for all odd $n$ gives the alternating sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}P_{(0,t]}(S_n)$$

Comment: Btw you've still got $$N(t) \ge  t \Leftrightarrow S_n \leq t$$ which should be $$N(t) \ge n \Leftrightarrow S_n \leq t$$

Comment: @GabrielBurns Now, I understand. Thank you so much. I also edited the typo.

Comment: your edit says you're still confused about the equivalence $N(t) \ge  n \Leftrightarrow S_n \leq t$.  I think the best way to think about it is by describing each expression in words: $$\bullet N(t) \text{ is the amount you count to by time }t$$$$\bullet S_n \text{ is the time it takes you to count to }n$$So the equivalence is simply saying that "We count to at least $n$ by time $t$" is the same as "$t$ is at least enough time to count to $n$".  Does that make it any clearer?